# Handle ajax errors and execute the promise chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to provide a fallback for the failed ajax requests.
I want a global solution so I won't have to change every call in the code.

I tried providing an `error` handler to `ajaxSetup`, but the problem is I couldn't execute the chained callbacks.

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
  error: function() {
    console.error('Error occurred')
    return $.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  }
})

$.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/0') // Id doesn't exist
  .then(todo => console.log(todo))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Expected output

```
Error occurred
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "...",
  ...
}
```

Comment: It's actually executed, you just forget to write the next command.
`return $.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
.then(todo=>console.log(todo));`

Comment: In my case, that's not possible, because there are lots of calls with their own `then`s and `catch`s, so I can't put all that logic in the error handler.

Answer (score 1):

From jQuery 3.0 the callback method accepted are: done, always, fail.
So, i would have called the callback fail and in the inner, i resend the ajax call wrapped into a properly function with dynamic id

```
const submit = (id) => {
      const xhr = $.getJSON(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
         .done(todo => console.log(todo))
         .fail(err => { console.error(err); submit(id++); });
};

submit(0);
```

Comment: I'm not trying to solve this exact problem (That was a demo example).
I'm looking to re-execute failed (and different) ajax requests and have them continue executing their on callback chain (`then`s and `catch`s)

Comment: yeah @salah3x i understand... this is only one method to perform the re-execution of failed ajax request: on fail resubmit, on done continue chain.
Maybe this can be expanded based on your domain workflow and logic implementation...